# Amazon Elastic BeansTalk Nginx configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been searching a solution how to configure nginx proxy server to work with websockets. I have ready found a bunch of solutions make that. But, these scripts patch nginx.conf in the instances. But my instances don't have nginx running. Nginx is run on a balancer.

So my question is how to patch nginx config on a balancer.

Comment: What type of balancer are you talking about? I don't think it is aws Elastic Load Balancing (ELB)

Comment: We have t2.micro instance with nginx installed right behind ELB. It allows us to do custom balance logic on nginx. 

You can also bind an ElasticIP directly to your instance with nginx installing and not use ELB at all howeverthis is quite risky, ELB is more safe, however our instance based balancer works without any downtime for more than yeas.

Anyway try to ask your question on http://serverfault.com/ for better suggestions. Amazon team is also very good in support, describe your task detailed and they will help, for sure.

Anyway custom instance with nginx as a balancer does it :)

Comment: @BMW I can't explain what type of balancer (that's why i'm asking this question). Any balancer that can pass the websockets for me.

Comment: So if you don't know, how can you insist nginx has been installed on the load balancer?

Comment: I need to configure nginx proxy to pass websockets, but it can't be configured. Only that we can do in console (ports 80/443, ssl, session stickness)

Comment: AWS Elastic Beanstalk is not so flexible, so maybe think to implement your request via CloudFormation with ELB+NGINX+your application.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is confusing, because you are saying you are using ELB *and* you want Nginx.  But you can't get websockets in Nginx with normal ELB, and you probably don't *need* Nginx with ELB except in specific situations.

You have two choices:

1) Continue to use ELB and Elasticbeanstalk. The problem is that ELB doesn't support websockets at all. See [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-for-nodejs/).  You'll need to stop using ELB as a HTTP proxy, and start using it as a TCP proxy.  The downside is that your app will now be exposed to your servers going up and down. (In a HTTP proxy, each request can go to a different server. In a TCP proxy, the request stays alive for the whole session, so when the server goes down, your client must 'deal with it.')

2) Run your own load balancer. Best practice is EIP + Nginx + HAProxy. This is quite a different question.